# How to yield inside firebase listener inside stream

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-dart

Using AngularDart and Firebase, the below code doesn't work because `yield` is inside an anonymous inner class. How might I rewrite this? I'm new to both Angular and Dart and couldn't find any examples for this.

Essentially I'm trying to listen for items inside a stream in my service, but I'm getting the actual item from firebase and need to pass these firebase items back to the stream.

In the service:

```
Stream<Item> itemStream() async* {
  final ref = database().ref("items");
  await ref.onChildAdded.listen((e) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = e.snapshot;
    Map parsedMap = snapshot.val();
    String id = snapshot.key;
    String property1 = parsedMap['property1'];
    String property2 = parsedMap['property2'];
    print(property1);
    print(property2);
    yield new Item(id, property1, property2); // invalid; yield does not work here.
  });
  // yield works here but it's no use here.
}
```

Component:

```
var stream = itemListService.itemStream();
await for (var item in stream) {
  print(item.id);
}
```

**Update:** I got around this by not using a service. However I thought using a service was better practice so that's why I wanted to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do two things.

1) Use a `StreamController`

2) (Better)

`Stream<Item> itemStream() {
  final ref = database().ref("items");
  return ref.onChildAdded.map((e) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = e.snapshot;
    Map parsedMap = snapshot.val();
    String id = snapshot.key;
    String property1 = parsedMap['property1'];
    String property2 = parsedMap['property2'];
    print(property1);
    print(property2);
    return new Item(id, property1, property2);
}`

Comment: ok so just don't use async on it? can't believe I didn't try that. Definitely will next time. gonna hopefully have time to build a small app on the weekend using this.